# Most significant samples that capture 80% of energy in Signal Processing

Tags: signal-processing

Is there any algorithm for the peak finder in numeric signal? For example if we have:

```
x = [ 0.01 -0.5 0.02 0.5 0.003 0.8 1 0 0 0 -1 0 0.0001 0 0 0 ]
```

As you see we have 5 peak sample:

```
 ( -0.5 , 0.5 , 0.8 , 1 , -1 )
```

These peaks must capture 80 % of energy of signal x?

Comment: sort and keep taking from the largest until > 80%? That will get the fewest peaks, but not the closest to 80%

Comment: Thank you David for reply and can you please correct my Matlab code if i'm wrong : x = [ 0.01 -0.5 0.02 0.5 0.003 0.8 1 0 0 0 -1 0 0.0001 0 0 0 ];
for i =1:numel(x)
  Treshold = 0.85;
  x_energy = abs((x).^2);
  x_sort = sort(x_energy); % sorted in ascending order of energy 
  cum_energy = cumsum(x_sort(end:-1:1));  % cumulative energy 
  ind = min(find(cum_energy >= Treshold * cum_energy(end)));
  num_sig_component (i) = ind ;
  end

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you finally mention you want to do this in Matlab.
Well, have this Pseudo-code instead:

```
power = x .^2 #element-wise squaring
total = sum(power)
sorted, indices = sort(power) # sort and note down permutation indices
max_indices = []
max_sum = 0
while sum < total * 0.8:
   currentpower = pop(sorted) # get the highest power
   currentindex = pop(indices)
   max_sum+=currentpower
   max_indices.append(currentindex)
return max_indices
```